# Haskell: How getContents works?

Tags: haskell, io

Why doesn't the following program print my input? It seems that `putStr` is not taking the input. How does `getContents` work?

```
main = do 
    contents <- getContents
    when (length contents < 10) $ putStr contents
```

However, this program prints the input line by line:

```
main = do 
    contents <- getContents
    putStr contents
```

Comment: What if you enter few lines and then press Ctrl-D?

Comment: @Yuras: It just terminates. No line is printed.

Comment: You are using Windows? On linux Ctrl-D closes stdin, I don't know how to do it on Windows.

Comment: That is strange, it works for me, outputing all the entered lines on Ctrl-D. Are you sure you entered less then 10 chars total?

Comment: ah, most likely you are expecting it to check *each* line for `length < 10`? No, it will output only if total number of charactes < 10

Comment: @Yuras: It was not clear to me that `getContents` reads everything from the standard input. I thought that it was similar to `getLine`, so I used to give the first program many lines as input, where the length of each line was less than 10 characters. That's why I asked how `getContents` works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### getContents gets everything. Linebuffering makes it line-by-line

`getContents` gets the entire input from a handle (eg file or user input), so your program

```
main = do 
    contents <- getContents
    putStr contents
```

reads the entire contents of the standard input and prints it. The only reason you see this line by line is that it's using linebuffering on the terminal, so `getContents` gets its incoming String a line at the time.

### Lazy evaluation

Haskell uses lazy evaluation, which means it only calculates something when it has to - it doesn't *need* calculate the end of the string you're printing to print the start of it, so it doesn't bother, and just prints what it has now. This lazy functions are able to return partial results when they can, rather than having to calculate everything first.

### A line at a time

You appear in comments to want to only print lines when they're short like this session:

```
don't print this it's long
print this
print this
this is also too long
boo!
boo!
```

but since `getContents` is **all** the input, it won't print anything unless the **total** length is less than 10. What you were after was something where it treats each line separately, more like

```
main = do
  contents <- getContents
  putStrLn . unlines . filter short . lines $ contents

short xs = length xs <= 10
```

Answer (score 3):

`getContents` reads all the `stdin`, but it works lazily. It returns a [thunk](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Thunk), it is a promise to return some value when you ask it (force the thunk).

`putStr` asks for one char at a time, forcing the thunk to return value. For lists (note, `String` is a list of `Char`s), thunk when forced returns either "end of of list" or pair of ("next char", "thunk for the rest of the list"). So the second example works because `putStr` outputs chars when they become available. You enter the next line -- `putStr` outputs it char-by-char, tries to force the next thunk, but blocks because the next char is not available yet.

The first example forces the thunk until it returns "end of the list", because it is not possible to know string length until it is available.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing an interactive application, getting the length of `getContents` is a bad idea. That's because the length the standard input can only be calculated when the stream is closed. Which means that you'd have to either use Ctrl+D on Linux, Ctrl+Z on Windows or close the application, before you got to see the results.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that. Thanks! However, I don't understand why the second program reads a line and then prints it. I thought it should read everything first (every line) and then print it.